# How can I retrieve my bitcoins when the client crashes as soon as it begins synchronizing

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, address, linux

As soon as the client begins synchronizing it crashes. It's stuck at 139,500 blocks left. I am brand new to bitcoin and sent $300 to an address on this client.

Comment: Can you give more details?

Try running the client from the command line.  Does it report any errors?

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way is probably to import the private key of the address to which you sent the bitcoins into [blockchain.info's web wallet service](http://blockchain.info/wallet).

- [obtain the private key for the address which holds your bitcoins](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4203/how-can-i-export-the-private-key-for-an-address-from-the-satoshi-client)
- visit https://blockchain.info/wallet/
- click 'start a new wallet' in the top left
- type a password twice, solve the captcha, and click 'continue'
- copy/paste the long url (https://blockchain.info/wallet/random-stuff-...) and keep it safe
- visit the url you just copied, and log in using the password you just chose
- click the import/export tab, then click 'continue'
- paste your private key into the 'import private key' box and click 'add private key'
- now you should see your balance, and can spend it from the blockchain.info web wallet

Alternatively, if you want to keep using the satoshi client, you might find it useful to download a [recent snapshot of the blockchain](http://eu1.bitcoincharts.com/blockchain/) and let it update from there.