# Wallet.dat Bitcoin core Privatekey Recovery

Tags: bitcoin-core, private-key

Is there any method from which we can manually calculate wallet privatekey from a protected bitcoin core wallet.dat file ?

I was searching on it and find this , I think it is related to my topic https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=4413938.0

Answer (score 1):

> **Is there any method from which we can manually calculate wallet privatekey ...**

You can't *calculate* the private-key.

You can *extract* the key if the wallet is unprotected or if the wallet is protected *and* you know the wallet passphrase (also known as the wallet "[password](https://bitcoin.org/en/secure-your-wallet#encrypt)").

You can do this using  [walletpassphrase](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/walletpassphrase.html) and [dumpprivkey](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.16.0/rpc/wallet/dumpprivkey/) in either Bitcoin-core's debug console or using its API.

You can also do this using the equivalent methods in other tools such as pywallet.

> **... from a protected bitcoin core wallet.dat file?**

Only if you know the passphrase for the protected wallet. Bitcoin core uses the password to encrypt the private key.

If you don't know the passphrase, you can't extract the private key.

---

Related:

- [How can I export the private key for an address from the satoshi client?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4203/13866)
- [How do I export my private keys from my Bitcoin-Qt client?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/7536/13866)
- [How can I export all my private keys using bitcoind?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4632/13866)