# I sent bitcoins to my wallet before it had synced. is there ANY way i can get my coins back?

Tags: blockchain, network, bitcoin-core, synchronization, wallet.dat

I downloaded Bitcoin. qt and started the sync (which was going to take about 6 days UGH) so about 4 days into it i tried to open the app and Now the app shows "error loading blkindex.dat" So i cannot access my wallet on my computer and never really got a chance to backup or encrypt anything...

I've tried using blockchain.info's desktop sync function but literally nothing happens when i press "download address list" on step 3...????

I have also tried MtGox but i can't find anywhere to upload my wallet.dat file...

Is there ANY WAY i can get my coins?

I'm running Mac OS X. Be as specific as you can please :)

Comment: You are running Bitcoin-Qt on iOS?   Wow!  

(Did you mean Mac OS X?)

Answer (score 4):

As long as your wallet.dat file is uncorrupted/unstolen, your coins are fine. Try backing up the wallet.dat file, uninstalling Bitcoin, then reinstalling.

Answer (score 2):

[Blockchain.info/wallet](http://blockchain.info/wallet) has the ability to import individual private keys as well.   The [private keys can be exported](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/5933/153) now right from the Bitcoin-Qt client (v0.7 and higher) directly without the need for pywallet or any other utility.