# How do I use my Bitcoin-Qt wallet address on Blockchain.info?

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info, passphrase

My Bitcoin-Qt client is still synchronizing with the network. I'm unsure of how to use my Bitcoin-Qt wallet address on [Blockchain.info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockchain.info). I've put my address on Blockchain.info as (watch only), but how do I get full access to my wallet on Blockchain.info?

I do have a passphrase and the wallet is locked. Does Bitcoin-Qt need to be fully synchronized with the network for me to be able to access my wallet?

Comment: The block chain can take a (very) long time to synchronize with.. patience, anon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I export the private key for an address from the satoshi client?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4203/how-can-i-export-the-private-key-for-an-address-from-the-satoshi-client)

Answer (score 1):

You have to unlock your wallet, export the private key for your address and then import it to Blockchain.info. You don't even need Bitcoin-Qt then, because ***they*** store your privkey and your ***money***!

Answer (score 1):

1. [Export](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4203/how-can-i-export-the-private-key-for-an-address-from-the-satoshi-client) the private key for a specific Bitcoin address from Bitcoin-Qt.  Copy the value to your clipboard.
2. Import it
   into Blockchain.info wallet (log into your Blockchain.info wallet,
   click Import/Export tab, for the Import Private Key field paste the
   private key.)