# I sent my bitcoins from LocalBTC to a unsynced bitcoin wallet program, the bitcoins are not showing up. How do i get them back?

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, private-key-export

I sent bitcoins from localbtc wallet to a unsynced program, it says 0 in the balance of the program and I really want them back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13294/help-i-sent-my-1-bitcoin-to-my-unsynced-bitcoin-wallet-program-how-do-i-get-the

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/6056/cannot-access-my-bitcoins-because-my-wallet-is-still-synchronising-what-can-i-d

Comment: I corrected the tags, I assume you are using the standard client, is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options: Either wait until your wallet has sychronized with the network – your bitcoin will show up when the block was processed that validated the transaction with which it was sent to you. The other option is that you can [export](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4203/how-can-i-export-the-private-key-for-an-address-from-the-satoshi-client?lq=1) the corresponding private keys to a client that doesn't store the blockchain and access it that way.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to open your wallet program and export the private key for the address(es) to which you sent the money. You would then import these private keys into a wallet program that doesn't require downloading the blockchain to work. Your best bets are BlockChain.info's web app and Electrum. Your balances should show up properly and immediately in those wallets and you'll be able to spend them freely.