# Is it possible to retrieve bitcoin address?

Tags: bitcoind, address, balance, daemon

I have Bitcoin daemon running in Amazon AMI, i have some balance in my bitcoin wallet, suppose i re-install os/daemon, is it possible to retrieve those balance what happened to that bitcoin addresses(Is it available in my wallet/all addresses will be lost?)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to [extract the private keys](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4203/how-can-i-export-the-private-key-for-an-address-from-the-satoshi-client) for the addresses that hold any balances into your wallet and then [import these keys back to your fresh installation](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/How_to_import_private_keys_v7+).