# How do I export a private key from my Bitcoin-QT wallet if the wallet isn't synced?

Tags: bitcoin-core, private-key, wallet-recovery, recover-private-key

I started syncing a bitcoin-qt client, and had somebody send me funds to an address generated in the client.

I then stupidly decided to speed up the syncing process and downloaded a torrent of bootstrap.dat which I loaded into the client.

Now the client is not syncing.

I still have the public address that I had the funds sent to, and I still have the wallet.dat

I would like to get the private key out of the wallet and then import it into an online wallet to at least get these funds before I start again with a local wallet.

Can this be done?

nb: In the client the `debug window` option is greyed out and cannot be selected.

thanks!

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether you are synced or not, you should be able to export your key. How to do that is described there: [How can I export the private key for an address from the satoshi client?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4203/5406).