# I sent bitcoins to my wallet before it was synced. Is there anyway to transfer the funds to a different wallet without waiting fo it to properly sync?

Tags: transactions, wallet, synchronization

I sent bitcoins to my wallet before it was synced. Is there anyway to transfer the funds to a different wallet without waiting for it to properly sync? The wallet still says no available funds or pending transactions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot access my bitcoins because my wallet is still synchronising. What can I do to spend them immediately?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/6056/5406), also see: [How can I export the private key for an address from the satoshi client?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4203/5406), alternatively, you can just wait for your wallet to finish synchronizing, but that might take a few hours.

Answer (score -1):

You could find the wallet file and attach it to a client that is already synced with the network.