# Migrate from Bitcoin Core Wallet to somewhere else before sync completed

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, synchronization, wallet.dat

I created a Bitcoin wallet yesterday using Bitcoin Core Wallet application and bought some bitcoin via buy.bitcoin.com to the address mentioned in File>Recieving Address in my Bitcoin Core Wallet. They sent the money but I can't see if I received it or not because I did it before synchronization complete and it seems it takes at least 2 weeks for my bitcoin core wallet to finish synchronization (I think the number is increasing):

[image]

Is there anyway I can move my wallet to some other bitcoin client and start using it instantly? I paid a lot of money to but bitcoins and it seems I can't use it until this app finish its synchronization.

If so, then which client and how?

Any help/guide will be appreciated.

Comment: Dump the private keys and import them in a wallet such as electrum

Comment: @RutgerVersteegden Can you let me know how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following these 3 easy steps helped me:

1. Download & Install [Electrum](https://electrum.org)
2. [Extract your private key](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4203/how-can-i-export-the-private-key-for-an-address-from-the-satoshi-client) from Bitcoin Core Wallet
3. Import your wallet using the private key