# Running out of disk space with Bitcoin Core

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, synchronization

A year ago I purchased some bitcoins and it was sent to my address. I loaded up Bitcoin Core and installed it to my laptop HD, it ran out of space on the HD, mid blockchain sync. It has now been a year. I have confirmation that the coins have been sent to the address and they are there, what can I do?

Comment: I don't really understand what you problem is. Your bitcoins are on an adress und if you have the private key, you have access. Why is the space of your disc relevant?

Comment: I'm very new to this i don't really know what I am doing, I don't have the private key, only the address.

Comment: You will want to verify your last statement. Without the private key, you can spend as much of the coins on that address as I can.

Comment: if you have wallet.dat file you can get private key of that address and get access to your bitcoins.

Answer (score -2):

How are you? WOW guessing you're rich now!
The proof you have bitcoin in your wallet does nothing. Bitcoin is not a system you can go and get your wallet back with showing them you have bitcoin in your wallet.
Go to blockchain.info and download the app. Click on add address. Scan your private key and then you can use your bitcoins again.
Hope you can gain access to your wallet.

Comment: Can I get my private key via bitcoin core? and then transfer it?

Comment: Any time you get your private key you can transfer your bitcoins.

Comment: A link that can help you to get your private key from bitcoin core:
https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4203/how-can-i-export-the-private-key-for-an-address-from-the-satoshi-client

Comment: Hey do you know how to get the barcode like scan to show up on bitcoin core? I think i have it but can you get ones for public and private?

Comment: It's not in bitcoin core. I meant if you had a barcode of your private key you can do that. or if you have your private key, download a barcode creator and use it to use it in blockchain.info app.

Comment: Find your private key. Copy it and save it. Then use a barcode app to change your private key into a barcode.