# wallet will not sync it has been a week and I still do not have my money in the wallet. It took out my account

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have video proof that this has been going on for a week I have restarted the computer multiple times and have yet to receive any money into my account. I do not even have a wallet number.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Bitcoin.SE! In order for someone to help, you'll need to provide more info, such as: what software are you using? What sort of errors are you receiving from the software? What do you expect to happen, and what actually happened? Where did you buy bitcoin from? Do you have a transaction ID for a transaction that was sent to you? Etc

Comment: I am using a Windows laptop, using Bitcoin Core Wallet. When i went to the bitcoin website to buy bitcoin it said i needed a wallet, therefore I downloaded BCW. It has now been six whole days and I have yet to see the deposit I made to the account to receive money. I do have a transaction ID from blockchain and it shows that all was approved, now I am just not seeing it in the wallet. As of now I want to know why for six days the BCW app on my laptop has shown that it is syncing for six days and has yet to give my money?

Answer (score 1):

You are using wallet-software that requires you to download the whole Bitcoin ledger before it can read your balance. The Bitcoin ledger (the blockchain) is currently about 210 gigabtyes, so you would need a very fast internet connection to download it in just six days. If you don't have 210 gigabytes of spare storage, your laptop's disk will fill up *before* it gets to the part of the blockchain with *your* transaction and you'll not be able to see it.

You may therefore want to consider importing your address into some other wallet-software that's able to read a *remote* copy of this enormous ledger. Such wallets are very popular, but ultra security-conscious people do like to have their own copies of the blockchain, and only you can decide how much security you need.

In the meantime, any blockexplorer web site will tell you whether or not your coins have been sent to your address. If they're at your address, you have nothing to worry about other than the minor inconvenience of *either* waiting for the blockchain to download *or* importing your address into some other wallet-software before you can spend your coins.

It will make more sense if you remind yourself that bitcoins are not stored in wallets. Wallets are just tools for drawing up & signing transactions (and they also let you view your balance). The coins themselves exist only on the blockchain.

***EDIT***
Putting together the information in your two comments, it sounds like you've already transferred your coins to an address controlled by you (check your address on a blockexplorer web site). If so, your predicament is like having a faulty debit card (*i.e.* the money's in your account but you can't see it). I suggest you study [how to export the private key](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4203/how-can-i-export-the-private-key-for-an-address-from-the-satoshi-client?noredirect=1&lq=1) for the address that you used. Once you've **ex**ported it, you can **im**port it into a lightweight wallet that doesn't insist on downloading the whole blockchain. Personally I would use Electrum, but [other lightweight wallet software is available](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet). Electrum has a *create new wallet* wizard, with an option to *“Import Bitcoin addresses or private keys”*, where you should be able to paste your exported private key.

Private keys are valuable to you and to anyone who hacks into your computer, so you want to proceed carefully. Consider disconnecting your computer from the internet during the export/import process. You don't need the internet for key management chores.

Comment: Thanks so much for this advice. How exactly do I transfer the funds from blockchain to another account say for example, "Upaycard"?

Comment: I've added to the answer above. Obviously, if you can't see your coins in a block explorer website, my edits don't help much, but your earlier comment says you have a transaction ID, so I'm assuming the transaction (you can look *it* up too, on a block exporer!) shows your coins moving to *your* address.